# Vim YouCompleteMe installation

Tags: plugins, vim

I'm trying to install [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) plugin alongside my [Vundle plugin manager for Vim](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim). I've just added the  `Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'` line to my ~/.vimrc and then I wrote`:PluginInstall` in Vim, but all I've got is "Processing 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'" and it lasts already an hour, so I guess it's not going to be installed. What's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all your plugins in a separate file. In my example I used `bundles.vim`. Then run the command `vim -c BundleInstall -c q -c q -u bundles.vim`

[Here is an example of the `bundles.vim` file](https://github.com/DenniJensen/vimfiles/blob/master/bundles.vim)

[Here is the command in a shell script](https://github.com/DenniJensen/vimfiles/blob/master/update_bundles.sh)

This combination will put all your plugins i a plugins folder and then the plugins will be ready for use if they don't need any third party library.

Comment: The links provided in this answer are no longer available.